# Conditionally use react imports

Tags: reactjs

I have these three imports and I want to use them accordingly.

```
import avatar1 from "../../../../assets/images/user/avatar-1.jpg";
import avatar2 from "../../../../assets/images/user/avatar-2.jpg";
import avatar3 from "../../../../assets/images/user/avatar-3.jpg";
```

And I have this map function and I want to show these three images as map function executes.

So I wrote this:

```
{this.state.empData.map((emp, index) => (
                          <tr className="unread" key={emp.id}>
                            <td>
                              {index + 1 <= 3 ? (
                                <img
                                  className="rounded-circle"
                                  style={{ width: "40px" }}
                                  src={`avatar` + { index }}
                                  alt="activity-user"
                                />
                              ) : (
                                (index = 0) // i want to reset the index, so it would start from 0 again
                              )}
                            </td>                                                        
                          </tr>
                        ))}
```

So what i want is, if I have 10 iterations through that `map` function, and I have 3 avatars, I want to show each 10 image so each 3 avatars are repeated from avatar1 to avatar3 as long as map iterates.

Above method I tried, doesn't work as images a re not showing.

Can you help me?

Comment: Some advice, since these are images you should probably be getting them via an api request or static folder. importing assets like this is mostly unnecessary. just use the url in the src attribute

Comment: Can I use the same path I mentioned in the import?

Comment: And how can I reset the `index` so it will again start from avatar1 after every 3 iterations?

Answer (score 2):

## Write a selector function and use the modulus

You can use modulus to repeat a series of numbers. it always returns the remainder of the division. e.g. `3 % 3 === 0` `6 % 3 === 0` `1 % 3 === 1`

```
const selectImage = (index) {
  if (index % 3 === 0) {
    return avatar1; // or return "../../../../assets/images/user/avatar-1.jpg"
  }
  if (index % 3 === 1) {
    return avatar2; // or return "../../../../assets/images/user/avatar-2.jpg"
  }
  if (index % 3 === 2) {
    return avatar3; // or return "../../../../assets/images/user/avatar-3.jpg"
  }
}
```

and then in your component

```
 <img
   className="rounded-circle"
   style={{ width: "40px" }}
   src={selectImage(index)}
   alt="activity-user"
 />
```

Comment: Unexpected token near angle bracket